# Getting syntax error while RegEx check

Tags: node.js, regex, url

This is the first time I am using RegEx in NodeJS.

AIM : very basic check on URL, if it's valid or not. I found [this regex](https://www.regextester.com/94502). Below is my code,

```
var URL = "https://www.google.com/";
var regEx = "^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$";
if(URL.match(regEx)) {
   console.log('matches');
} else {
   console.log('doesnt match');
}
```

Now, I am getting some syntax error, and I can't find the solution. Error is like, "Range out of order in character class". I have no idea about character class or RegEx. Please, someone help :) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are providing your regex as `String`

Try following

```
var URL = "https://www.google.com/";
var regEx = /^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$/;

if(URL.match(regEx)) {
    console.log('matches');
} else {
    console.log('doesnt match');
}
```

You can read https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp for more details on regex in javascript.

```
var t = /^foo(bar)?$/i;
alert(t instanceof RegExp);//returns true
```

Keep in mind that as Regex is not a primitive data type but its a objext of RegExp (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: ohh, okay. thanks for clarification :) . one simple doubts, are u saying that regex is entirely different data-type in javascript ?.

Answer (score 0):

**Change the code as bellow**

```
var URL = "https://www.google.com/";
var regEx = /^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\ 
(\)\*\+,;=.]+$/;
if(URL.match(regEx)) {
   console.log('matches');
 } else {
   console.log('doesnt match');
 }
```